# Custom query for Visual Composer's Post Grid in Word Press

Tags: wordpress, query-string, post

A site in Word Press. It has several custom post types. Each of them has several taxonomies that, coincidentally, are the same. Specifically:

```
 - Press <-- CPT
    - Country   <-- Taxonomy
    - Theme 
    - Department

- Resources
    - Country
    - Theme
    - Department
```

I'm using **Visual Composer** and need to use the **Post Grid** module, which lets you create a **custom query** in "one-line" format such as `posts_per_page=3&post_type=post&post_status=publish&orderby=date&order=DESC`

### THE QUESTION

What's the one-line query to output the most recent 5 posts from BOTH custom post types within the taxonomy "Country"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! The string has to be URL-encoded containing an array for the field "post-type" and also the "[ ]" characters are not allowed so must output the url-encoded value which is `%5B%5D`.

```
post_type%5B%5D=press
&post_type%5B%5D=resources
&cat=country
&post_status=publish
&order_by=date
&order=DESC
```